Risk-Reversal cost in the Vanna-Volga pricing
To hedge the Vanna in the Vanna-Volga pricing, the methodology does not use the market price of the risk-reversal but uses the difference between the market price (with skew/smile) and the theoretical price (no skew/smile) (same process for Volga).
If the goal is to set up a replicating portfolio for the Vanna and volga exposure to adjust the option's price, why not using the market prices of the RR and BF directly instead of the difference in prices? Given the market prices are what a dealer would spend to hedge the vanna/volga of the option.

(Too long for a comment)
Because it's the difference between the market price and the flat vola price that gives the cost of the vega-vanna-volga hedge.
The assumption of VV pricing is that you are given the market prices of three options (or alternatively RR and BF). It is then assumed that the market prices of these "pillar options" can be decomposed into a flat vola price and an adjustment due to the cost of hedging vega, vanna and volga.
The VV method then says that the VV (market) price of any vanilla option can be expressed as the sum of a flat vola price (the same flat vola that is used for the RR and BF) and an adustment due to the cost of hedging vega vanna volga. This cost, in turn, can be expressed in terms of the cost of the vega,vanna,volga hedge of the RR and BF.
More details in this paper by Castagna and Mercurio, if you've not already read it.
